Как модифицировать Dockerfile для копирования объектов перед запуском сервера?
Добрый день!
У меня есть Dockerfile следующего содержания:
FROM python:3.8-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc musl-dev libffi-dev postgresql-dev python3-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev\
    icu-dev \
    gettext \
    gettext-dev

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Moscow /etc/localtime

COPY . .

CMD sh -c "python manage.py migrate --no-input && python manage.py collectstatic --no-input && daphne -b 0.0.0.0 -p 80 application.asgi:application"

После каждого перезапуска контейнеров мне приходится вручную в консоли сервера выполнять следующую команду, чтобы подменять один из файлов библиотеки на собственный:
docker cp ./article/static/django_summernote.css a7bd45dd25ab:./app/static/summernote

Как мне прописать данную команду в Dockerfile, чтобы не выполнять это каждый раз вручную?

Вы в принципе не должны так делать. Все необходимые статические файлы должны быть добавлены в ваши Django-приложения, и команда collectstatic их автоматически подхватит

@andreymal я понимаю, но конкретно в этом случае это необходимо. Прошу, подскажите решение моего вопроса - если знаете. Спасибо!

Почему это необходимо?

@andreymal потому что библиотека django_summernote , в статикфайлах которой я хочу подменить два объекта, орисовывает на странице сайта iframe, не взаимодействующий с основной страницей. Дополняющий код файлов как раз необходим для того, чтобы получить некоторые данные из материнской вёрстки во внутреннюю.

Для подмены статического файла достаточно добавить его в своё Django-приложение, как я написал в первом комментарии. Не вижу необходимости городить костыли

Кроме того, в документации django-summernote описано несколько официальных способов добавления своих стилей, так что неочевидно, зачем тут вообще что-то подменять

@andreymal если не сложно, подскажите решение по существу вопроса. Я буду благодарен ссылке на документацию, но изучу её позже.
